# SQL Server Batching Large inserts and Updates Within a Transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batching

I have been working on offloading data from a very large table(Close to 400 million records) in a SQL Server 2016 environment. I have been doing so by updating a column in the table used as a delete flag. The procedure also offloads the data into a separate table for archiving purposes. The flag is to be used by a procedure at the end of every month to delete the rows in the main table where deletion is flagged.

My goal is to have an efficient procedure with minimal blocking as the table in question is used quite frequently.

From what I have been reading online about the matter, the best way to deal with large updates and inserts is through batching to avoid blocking as much as possible, however, marking the main table and inserting into the archive table need to happen within a transaction to be sure one does not complete without the other, or the end of month deletion may end up deleting without archiving.

Is batching the best course of action when done inside a transaction since the transaction uses an exclusive lock anyway?

Is there a better method I could be using?

Comment: Batching is only as effective as it can be if you use fewer transactions. (Wrapping 10 * 1000-row inserts in a single transaction is virtually the same as wrapping 1 * 10000-row insert.)

Comment: You can use DELETE ... OUTPUT INTO to avoid the scenario where you delete without archiving or vice-versa. But I strongly recommend _against_ this type of data movement for archiving purposes. Here's what happens: (1) you write the original row (2) you update the row (soft delete) (3) you write the row somewhere else (4) you delete the original row. So that's 4 writes, times the number of indexes, plus any other updates that happen to the row before it is archived. Multiply that by how many secondaries or other log-reading traffic is in place. That's a LOT of writes for one row.

Comment: Instead, use partitioning. Instead of moving data anywhere, you just switch out the "archived" partition when it ages out. Fast. Metadata-only. No data movement, so no need to batch anything. No concerns over impact to log.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I was spinning my wheels trying to optimize my other code. After doing a bit of research,  partitioning seems like the perfect fit